# list the files with minimum sequence

Tags: perl, bash, unix, sed, awk

I have some files in a directory as below (not necessarily sorted):

```
A_10
A_20
A_30
B_10
B_30
C_10
C_20
D_20
D_30
E_10
E_20
E_30
```

`10`, `20` and `30` are the sequence numbers of `A,B,C,D,E` respectively.

I want to select only those files with minimum sequence of all `A,B,C,D,E`
the output should be :

```
A_10
B_10
C_10
D_20
E_10
```

could anybody help me?

Comment: respectively is a one-to-one relationship, so it is not possible that 10,20,30 are sequence numbers of A,B,C,D,E respectively...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -le '
  print join $/, 
    grep !$_{( split "_" )[0]}++, 
      sort glob "*_*"
  '
```

or:

```
printf '%s\n' *_* | sort | awk -F_ '!_[$1]++'
```

or:

```
printf '%s\n' *_* | sort -t_ -uk1,1
```

Answer (score 4):

In bash:

```
for x in A B C D E; do
    ls -1 ${x}_* | sort | head -n1
done
```