# Keep only one version of each file (bash)

Tags: bash

I want to remove redundant files in a folder. Something like

```
cat_1.jpg
cat_2.jpg
cat_3.jpg
dog_10.jpg
dog_100.jpg
```

reduced to

```
cat_3.jpg
dog_100.jpg
```

That is, take only the version of each file with the highest number suffix and delete the rest.

This is very much like

[list the files with minimum sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027939/list-the-files-with-minimum-sequence?rq=1)

but the bash answer there has a "for ... in ... ". I have thousands of file names.

EDIT:

Got the file name convention wrong. There may be other underscores (ex. cat_and_dog_100.jpg). I need it to only take the number after the last underscore.

Comment: I'd use a Perl script, side-stepping `bash`.  Python or Ruby could be used instead.  Care is required to ensure that `fish_90.jpg` is removed and `fish_103.jpg` is kept.

Comment: In the future, consider using proper version control software instead of numbered file names.

Comment: Is the filename predictable, i.e always `<name>_<numbers>.jpg`?

Comment: I didn't make these file names. They're from making a copy of a website. And yes, they are predictable: there will be only one underscore between the name and the number and nowhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your filenames are always in the form `<name>_<numbers>.jpg`, here's a quick hack:

```
while read filename; do
    prefix=${filename/%_*/}  # Get text before underscore
    if [ "$prev_prefix" != "$prefix" ]; then  # we see a new prefix
        echo "Keeping filename"
        prev_prefix=$prefix
    else  # same prefix
        echo "Deleting $filename"
        rm $filename
    fi
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg"| sort -n -t'_' -k1,2)
```

How this works:

1. Sorts all `*.jpg` files first by `<name>` and then by `<numbers>`.

   - all files with the same prefix will be grouped together with the highest `<number>` appearing first
2. Iterates through the list of filenames and delete files except when a new `<name>` is found (which should be the one with the highest `<number>` )

Note that `find` is used instead of `ls *.jpg` so we can better handle large number of files.

---

*Disclaimer: This is a rather fragile way of dealing with files and versioning, and should not be adopted as a long term solution. Do heed the comments posted on the question.*